# Why can't I get overlay scrollbars in GNOME3?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, overlay-scrollbars

How do I enable the overlay-scrollbars in GNOME3?

Answer (score 3):

Overlay scrollbars haven't been ported to GTK3 yet so they won't work until this work is done.

This porting will be done sometime during the 11.10 cycle.